# Right Hasse diagram for a partial order?

Tags: relations

$A = \{(−7, 1), (−5, 1), (−3, 1), (−1, 1), (−7, 3), (−5, 3), (−3, 3), (−1, 3),
(−7, 5), (−5, 5), (−3, 5), (−1, 5), (−7, 7), (−5, 7), (−3, 7), (−1, 7)\}$

I tried to plot it and got the following:

[image: Hasse Diagram of $A$]

I feel like it is incorrect due to the amount of lines.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Gher is 16 lines.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.
But there is no reason to draw the lower and the upper elements with that slope.
You **don't** have, for example, $-7<-5$, under this order.

Notice also this is not really a partial order, since $A$ is not reflexive.
But perhaps you really mean $X=\{-7,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7\}$ and $\leq \,= \Delta_X \cup A$, where $$\Delta_X=\{(x,x):x\in X\}.$$
As it is, what you have is a representation of the bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$.